# how to initialize Empty array in stuct [Solidity]

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am suffering to initialize an empty array for struct when a struct is made.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract Board {

    //storage
    Post[] posts;

    //struct
    struct Post {
        address author;
        string title;
        string content;
        Comment[] comments;
    }

    struct Comment {
        address author;
        string comment;
    }

    //add-post
    function addPost(address _author, string memory _title, string memory _content) public {
        posts.push(Post(_author, _title, _content, /* HERE IS THE PROBLEM POINT */));
    }
}
```

I want to initialize the comments(struct member) with Empty Array(Type: Comment).
Which code should I use for The Problem Point??

Lang : Solidity

Thx.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I don't know how solve this problem. I changed store a little bit, now it works, maybe it will be helpful for you

P.s in 0.4.25 version you can return all post comments, but in 0.5.1 I assume that its not support as default yet

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract Board {

    //storage
    uint256 public postAmount = 0;
    mapping(uint256 => Post) public posts;

    struct Comment {
        address author;
        string comment;
    }

    struct Post {
        address author;
        string title;
        string content;
        Comment[] comments;
    }

    //add-post
    function addPost(address _author, string memory _title, string memory _content, string memory _comment) public {
        Post storage post = posts[postAmount];
        post.author = _author;
        post.title = _title;
        post.content = _content;

        bytes memory tempEmptyString = bytes(_comment);
        if (tempEmptyString.length != 0) { // check if comment exists
            post.comments.push(Comment({
                 author: _author,
                 comment: _comment
            }));
            postAmount++;
        }
    }

    function getComment(uint256 _postIndex, uint256 _commentIndex) public view returns(string memory) {
        Post memory post = posts[_postIndex];
        return post.comments[_commentIndex].comment;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank U I am impressed by ur answer. what if there is no initial comment, how should I handle this?

Comment: In my code comment is optional

If there is no initial comment, it'll just create post without pushing in comments array or with empty array (if there are no comments yet)